# Why is this bash program so fast or the perl program so slow?

Tags: bash, perl

I have this Bash program:

```
dict_fn='/usr/share/dict/american-english'
benchmark_repetitions=100
for i in `seq 1 $benchmark_repetitions` ; do
    readarray -t syllables < 'syllables.txt'
    for syllable in "${syllables[@]}" ; do
        matches=$(grep "$syllable" $dict_fn | wc -l)
        #echo "${syllable}: $matches"
    done
done
```

It runs in about 4 seconds on my laptop

```
$ time t.sh 

real    0m3,488s
user    0m4,103s
sys 0m0,910s
```

with this input file **syllables.txt**:

```
art
bur
cic
dun
eik
fum
gaw
hiw
irc
jaw
kry
lus
mac
noq
old
pew
qla
rub
sur
tif
uks
```

Then I tried to do the same in Perl:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use experimental qw(declared_refs refaliasing signatures);

{
    my $benchmark_repetitions = 100;
    for (1..$benchmark_repetitions) {
        my \@lines = read_dict();
        my \@syllables = read_syllables();
        for my $syllable (@syllables) {
            my @matches = grep /\Q$syllable/, @lines;
            my $num_matches = scalar @matches;
            #say "${syllable}: ${num_matches}";
        }
    }
}

sub read_syllables() {
    my $fn = 'syllables.txt';
    return read_file($fn);
}

sub read_dict() {
    my $fn = '/usr/share/dict/american-english'; # A file with more than 100,000 words
    return read_file($fn);
}

sub read_file( $fn ) {
    open ( my $fh, '<', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
    chomp(my @lines = <$fh>);
    close $fh;
    return \@lines;
}
```

But this script ran to my surprise much slower:

```
$ time p.pl

real    0m13,392s
user    0m13,369s
sys 0m0,021s
```

I thought that the perl script would be faster since it did not call the external commands `grep` and `wc` like the bash script does. Any ideas why the Bash script is so fast, or alternatively, why the Perl script is so slow?

Comment: You can probably speed up the Bash script some more; `grep -Fc "$syllable" "$dict_fn"`

Comment: @tripleee That just makes the result even more surprising! 

Comment: [off-topic] use a tool like [hyperfine](https://github.com/sharkdp/hyperfine) for much more accurate benchmarking results, esp. when it comes to command line utilities

Comment: It is most likely due to perl using "line oriented" file operations on 100_000 lines file.

Comment: It seems this is `grep` vs. `perl` rather than `bash` vs. `perl`.

Answer (score 5):

The crux of this is clearly in the filtering of so many lines, where Perl's `grep` runs a regex engine every time; it appears that system's `grep` is just that much faster, what I find unsurprising.  (Even as the actual performance ratio may be.)

As a little check, replace

```
my $num_matches = () = grep /\Q$syllable/, @$lines;
```

with

```
my $num_matches = () = grep index($_,$syllable) != -1, @$lines;
```

and my runtime gets cut in half.<sup>†</sup>

I get rid of the array (`@matches`) since bash code doesn't have one for that but directly pipes the list to `wc` (small speedup).  I also removed the experimental features so that this is more accessible (to older Perls), what doesn't make much difference.

While this brings us reasonably close we'd still need a considerable speedup to catch up but I don't see where to get that much.  Perhaps system's `grep` and handling of files is just faster.

---

<sup>†</sup>  Actually a bit further.  Here is a complete update.

As @tripleee answer shows, turning things around and checking all syllabi for each line (instead of all lines for each syllabus) brings about a further good improvement. Then, one can also check all syllabi with one regex invocation, as done in their answer, what improves things yet more. Finally, reading line by line (instead of reading all lines first) turns out faster yet.

My timings of ten iterations, on a server with CentOS7 and perlbrew-ed v5.36.0, using the system's dictionary at /usr/share/dict/linux.words with 479,828 lines, 4,8M), are:

OP code takes about 14s, that code with the change from this answer (`index` instead of regex) goes in under 6s (~5.5 -- 5.8s), and @tripleee code in just around/below 4s.

Comment: To my surprise, I found that `awk 'NR==FNR { a[++n] = $0; next } { for(i=1; i<=n; ++i) if ($0~a[i]) ++c[a[i]] } END {for(i=1; i<=n; ++i) print c[a[i]], a[i] }' /tmp/syllables.txt /usr/share/dict/american-english` was also slower than the Bash script. My suspicion is that there's a bug in it but I haven't finished looking at the results.

Comment: Both of these (the Bash script with `grep` and my Awk hack) count the number of words which contain at least one occurrence of a syllable; if the intent is really to count how many times a syllable occurs, the results are wrong for any word which contains the same syllable more than once.

Comment: @tripleee Yes, that's a kind of a thing I'd expect to come close.  Perhaps shell's handling of files with `grep` is just superior to all this hand-rolled code in a programming language?

Comment: @tripleee "_ if the intent is..._" -- uh, I took the intent to be to count lines with it, so one occurrence in a line.  That's what my little Perl demo does (otherwise I couldn't get rid of a regex with `index` that simply!)

Comment: @tripleee `$0~a[i]` is extremely slow with gawk. Try `index($0, a[i])` instead, or just use mawk.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I get a 30% improvement with that but still Awk is much slower than either Perl or the Bash script.

Comment: @tripleee huh, weird. It's faster than both bash and  perl on my computer.

Answer (score 3):

As commented by AnFi, the real bottleneck here is that you read the entire file into memory needlessly in your Perl version.

As a simple baseline, reading the syllables into memory and then looping over the big file line by line brings my baseline down to 0.5 seconds, down from 1.5 seconds from reading both files into memory and then quitting. But even this no-op baseline is slower than `grep` in a loop! (0.18 seconds with your code; marginally faster with `grep -Fc`.)

The fastest Perl implementation I could pull off takes 4 seconds; a slightly incorrect Perl version which produces wrong results got it down to 3.8 seconds.

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

{
    open(my $fh, '<', shift @ARGV);
    chomp (my @syllables = <$fh>);
    close $fh;

    my %syllable = map { $_ => 0 } @syllables;
    while (<>) {
        for my $match (@syllables) {
            $syllable{$match} += 1 if index($_,$match) != -1;
        }
    }
    for my $match (@syllables) {
        say "${match}: $syllable{$match}";
    }
}
```

(Credit for the `index` hack goes to @zdim.)

The slightly incorrect one fails because there are overlaps between the regular expressions, so if you have "art" and "tar" in the syllables, "tartan" will match "tar" but then not match "art".

```
    my $regex = "(" . join("|", @syllables) . ")";
    while (<>) {
        for my $match ($_ =~ qr($regex)) {
            ++$syllable{$match};
        }
    }
```

I tried to fool around with non-overlapping regexes and named regex groups but all the alternative solutions I could come up with were much slower.

Wait, hang on, here is 3.1 seconds with a simple lookahead.

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

{
    open(my $fh, '<', shift @ARGV);
    chomp (my @syllables = <$fh>);
    close $fh;

    my %syllable = map { $_ => 0 } @syllables;
    my $regex = "(?=(" . join("|", @syllables) . "))";
    my $re = qr{$regex(?:.|$)};
    while (<>) {
        my %seen;
        for my $match ($_ =~ m/$re/go) {
            next if $seen{$match}++;
            ++$syllable{$match};
        }
    }
    for my $syll (@syllables) {
        say "${syll}: $syllable{$syll}";
    }
}
```

(This is on a Mac, with 10 iterations and input from `/usr/share/dict/web2` which is probably different from your `american-english` file, but not too different. 235886 words, 2493109 bytes. I refactored the tests to all run in a Bash loop and had the Perl script just produce the result once.)

I would vaguely speculate that `grep` does some sort of memory mapping which behaves more or less ideally with the OS buffering, but I have not looked into this in any detail. The `grep` on MacOS is the BSD heritage, and different from what you probably have on Linux. (You haven't revealed your platform, so I'm speculating some more here.)

Comment: If you wanted to go wicked fast and all the syllables are always guaranteed to be three characters long, I can think of some optimizations; but I didn't want to hard-code the syllable lengths.

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting! I would like to test this, could you share the complete script? How did you implement the outer benchmark loop?

Comment: Reading the dictionary line by line, and using the map and index function as you showed, reduces runtime from 13s to 8s here. See https://github.com/hakonhagland/bash-vs-perl-grep-loop for details on my setup

Comment: I uploaded my cruft to https://replit.com/@tripleee/grep-vs-perl-vs-py#sya but I only uploaded a small subset of `american-english` from a Debian box.

Comment: GNU Awk on `repl.it` is quite fast but the Awk I have here, alas, is not.

Comment: You seem to be mixing me and the OP

Comment: @tripleee I meant for both of you to get notified, and you will as owner so I'm tagging OP as well.  Sorry about the confusion :)

Comment: My timings: OP code takes about 14s, that code with the change from my answer (`index` instead of regex) goes in under 6s (~5.7s is best), this code in just around 4s. So we kinda match `grep` + system's handling of files and that ain't bad at all!  A detail: I find that checking all syllabi against one line, instead of checking one syllabus for all lines, gives the bulk of improvement (~4.5s), in spite of the need for a hash.  Then reading line by line moves it by another half second over reading all lines first (and I'm not sure I understand why that is so).  (Note to OP @HåkonHægland)

Comment: The above is on a server with CentOS7 and perlbrew-ed v5.36.0, using the system's dictionary at /usr/share/dict/linux.words with 479,828 lines, 4,8M).  I time this code using `time for i in {1..10}; do ...; end` in bash, while OP/my code is set up to run 10 times.

Comment: @tripleee I consolidated my comments (and hopefully made it clearer who they are for)